# updating UIView heightAnchor

Tags: swift

I have a scrollView which has a contentView. The contentView is where other UI like a TableView components are placed but the problem I am having is resizing the hight of the contentView with the contentSize of the tableView

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.view.frame.size.height).isActive = true
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.view.frame.size.height)            
}

func makeUI() {

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(tableView)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height + self.tableView.contentSize.height)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor),
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.height + self.tableView.contentSize.height)
    ])            
}
```

how can I update the contentViewHeight because the `scrollView.contentSize` get updated.

Comment: Use a `contentSize` observer.

Comment: how do I do that @Sulthan?

Comment: @King do you want to delete or add items to tableview after view?